# Is Array of size 0 illegal by definition?

Tags: arrays, programming-languages

Is Array of size 0 illegal by definition or it depends on language?

Comment: "Array" means radically different things in different languages. Please be more specific.

Comment: By definition of *which language*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not illegal by definition, yet it does depend on the language.  Java is fine with it, depending on the compiler used in C you might have trouble with it but in general it works there too.

Somewhat related discussion on C++ and zero length arrays: [Array of zero length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295027/array-of-zero-length)