# Infinity value and buffer

Tags: c++

i have a score board that get update all time with new  information and the buffer size is = amount of rows my 
score board can handel, but i'm trying to make it infinity  without limits.

what i'm trying to do is as-sign infinity value to a buffer like that:

```
 const int infinity = std::numeric_limits<const int>::infinity(); 

 char Buffer_format_text [infinity];
```

but it dont work, becouse it says:

**error C2057: expected constant expression
 error C2466: cannot allocate an array of constant size 0**

is there a way to do that? or trick? , please help me. Don't ask me why i want to do that, i'm asking how to do that.

**Update:**

This how i'm doing it with sprintf , how do you that in ostringstream ?

```
char Buff[100]; 
int length  = 0;
int amount_of_space = 8;
length += sprintf(Buff+length,"%-*s %s\n", amount_of_space, "Test", "Hello");
```

```
this output: Test     Hello
```

Comment: Since it's C++, why you don't use string?

Comment: show me example using string as buffer with sprintf

Comment: @annaSjolvikaz Why `sprintf()`? Why not `std::ostringstream`?

Comment: becouse i dont know how to use std::ostringstream and get the lenght of it.. show me how

Comment: @annaSjolvikaz: Maybe google first, and if something specific is unclear, then ask?

Comment: I think someone deserve a sccepted anwser

Comment: Have you ever used `cin` and `cout`? It's very similar. Start off with those.

Comment: I don't think you realize just how big infinity actually is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't make sense to declare a buffer as big as infinity, both because integral types cannot (normally) represent infinity (the `infinity` member of `numeric_limits` is there for FP types), and because no machine could create a buffer infinity bytes big. :)

Instead, use a container that can handle the reallocations needed for new insertions by itself, limited only by the available memory, e.g. `std::vector` (or `std::deque` or others, depending from your insertion/removal patterns).

---

Edit: since the question seem to be about creating an arbitrarily long string, the "C++ answer" is to use `std::ostringstream`, which allow you to write as many elements as you like (limited only by the available memory) and provides you a `std::string` as a result.

```
std::ostringstream os;
for(int i=0; i<1000; i++)
    os<<rand()<<" ";
std::string out=os.str();
// now in out you have a concatenation of 1000 random numbers
```

---

Edit/2:

> This how i'm doing it with sprintf , how do you that in ostringstream ?
>
> ```
> char Buff[100]; 
> int length  = 0;
> int amount_of_space = 8;
> length += sprintf(Buff+length,"%-*s %s\n", amount_of_space, "Test", "Hello");
> ```

```
// needed headers: <sstream> and <iomanip>
std::ostringstream os;
int amount_of_space = 8;
os<<std::left<<std::setw(amount_of_space)<<"Test"<<" "<<"Hello";
std::string out=os.str(); // you can get `length` with `out.size()`.
```

But if you need to do multiple insertions call `os.str()` only at the end, when you actually need the string. Again, no need to keep track of length, the stream does it automatically.

Comment: I see, can you sow example using victor with sprintf instead of  char buffer[100....]

Comment: @annaSjolvikaz: As the comment above says - use ostringstream, or retag your question as C, not C++

Comment: @annaSjolvikaz: use `ostringstream` instead of `sprintf`, it handles the memory reallocations by itself and returns a `std::string`.

Comment: Can you give me small examlpe os using ostringstream like sprintf, get the lenght and do such lenght += sprintf(buff+lenght  etc??

Comment: @annaSjolvikaz: you don't use `ostringstream` like `sprintf`, you use it like a normal C++ stream; the bookkeeping about the current position in the string, the reallocations & co. is done automatically, see my example.

Comment: That example dont help, becouse i want to format the text like sprintf and use the lenght of text to make rows

Comment: @annaSjolvikaz Edit your question to show an example of what you're doing with `sprintf()`. Then we can show you how to do that with `std::ostringstream`.

Comment: @annaSjolvikaz: if you actually stated your real, complete question instead of changing the target at every comment it would be actually feasible to provide you a sensible answer.

Comment: Just updated my question to show how i'm doing with sprintf , how do you that in ostringstream ?

Answer (score 6):

In C++11, `infinity()` is `constexpr`, so **in theory** you could use it directly this way:

```
char Buffer_format_text[std::numeric_limits<const int>::infinity()];
```

However, the problem here is that `int` **cannot represent infinity**. If you tried this:

```
std::cout << std::numeric_limits<const int>::has_infinity;
```

You would see that `0` (`false`) is printed to the standard output ([**live example**](http://ideone.com/CrXozo)). The `infinity()` function for specializations of `std::numeric_limits` where `has_infinity` is `false` will return 0 - in fact, the function is meaningless in those cases - and you cannot create arrays of size 0.

Besides, you cannot expect an array of infinite size to be allocated - how would it fit into memory? The right approach, if you do not know in advance the size of your vector, is to use `std::vector` or a similar container that does allocate memory upon request.

---

**UPDATE:**

It seems what you actually need an infinite array for is to be able to build up a string whose size is not known in advance. To encapsulate such a string that grows dynamically, you can use [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string).

In order to perform type-safe output into an `std::string` and replace `sprintf()`, you could use [`std::ostringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream). That would allow you to insert stuff into a string the same way you would print it to the standard output.

Then, once you are done working with the `std::ostringstream`, you can get an `std::string` object from it by calling the `str()` member function.

This is how you could use it in a simple example:

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
    std::ostringstream oss;

    oss << "The answer is: ";
    oss << 42;
    oss << ", and this is a double: ";
    oss << 3.14;
    oss << ". " << std::endl;
    oss << "Oh, btw, you can also output booleans: ";
    oss << std::boolalpha << true;
    oss << ". See? It's easy!" << std::endl;

    std::cout << oss.str();
}
```

[**Live demo**](http://ideone.com/qg0cdh).

Comment: I see, can you show me small code using ostringstream as sprintf ?

Comment: @annaSjolvikaz: How is this related to the question?

Comment: @annaSjolvikaz: OK, now it makes sense. I updated my answer to show how you could use `std::ostringstream`.

Answer (score 2):

You basically cannot allocate an array with really infinite memory, either on stack or on the heap.
You also cannot allocate array with size 0 since it is illegal according to the standard.

You may try to use std::vector which grows when necessary by itself. but you still cannot have `infinite` memory to allocate since your disk space is limited no matter how large it is.

Comment: Why we can not make an array with size `0`? Ignoring the usage, it's possible.

Comment: @MM.: No, it's not. The standard forbids this

Comment: @MM. I found a post for why array length cannot be 0 in C++. so correct if I am wrong: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6180012/array-with-size-0

Comment: @MM.: Not sure what you mean, but the standard forbids having zero-sized arrays

Comment: @MM. the compiler may not give you warnings, but it does not make sense to declare arrays with 0 in length, you simply cannot use it anyway.

Comment: @AndyProwl: Would you indicate the paragraph of the standard which described it? (If it's possible)

Comment: @MM.: It's 8.3.4/1: "*[...] If the constant-expression (5.19)
is present, it shall be a converted constant expression of type std::size_t and its value shall be greater
than zero. [...]*"

Comment: @AndyProwl: You're so fast!! My bad English, the word _shall_ is a piece of advice or it means _must_ ?

Comment: @MM.: No problem, it means "must" - it has to be greater than zero

Answer (score 0):

You should use a container which can grow dynamically, such as `std::vector` (or, as your case seems to be text, `std::string`).

You can use `std::ostringstream` to construct a `std::string` like this:

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>

std::ostringstream ss;
ss << std::setw(amount_of_space) << std::left << "Test" << ' ' << "Hello" << '\n';
std::string result = ss.str();
```

Comment: Just update my question, becouse i'm asking for the last part