# Can I use `operator delete[]` for a single element array allocation?

Tags: c++

If we allocate an object of size 1 as below

```
int *arr = new int[1];
```

Should we delete the object using `operator delete[]` or `operator delete`?

The reason I am concerned is if the compiler would be smart enough to convert the statement as a single element allocation `int *arr = new int` which would cause calling `operator delete[]` UB.

User Case:

I have a pointer, which I would end up allocation in a varied ways but would finally like to get it deleted. So was wondering, for single element allocation, if I consistently use `int *arr = new int[1]` can I consistently and safely use `operator delete[]`

**Note**

Can you please refer me back to the standards to support your answer?

Comment: `operator delete[]` of course. `int[1]` is not `int`. Compiler *smart enough* won't convert the statement.

Comment: It is the same place in the standard that tells you to call `delete[]` after `new[]`. there is no special case for size 1.

Comment: *If* the compiler *was* smart enough to do that (though changing one type into another hasn't anything to do with smartness at all), it would have to inform you of this change or this change would have to be specified in the standard and in this case it wouldn't be smartness either, but mandatory. If it was silently behind the back then that compiler wasn't smart but *intentionally evil*. No need for any standard document apart form common sense, an `int` just *is not the same* as an `int[1]`. Is a one-element array still an array (hint: answer hidden in this comment)?

Comment: It's probably worth pointing out, too, that there are practically no known cases where you should use `new[]`.

Comment: This is a silly question. It doesn't matter how "smart" a compiler is, it cannot introduce undefined behaviour (1.9 [intro.execution] p5) and require the programmer to alter source code that is correct, and you already know that using `delete[]` with `new[]` is correct and required by the standard. Such an optimisation by a "smart" compiler would mean the program works on one compiler and not another. That way madness lies.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You must use `delete[]` and not `delete`. The compiler is not allowed to change `new int[1]` to `new int`.

(As `int` is a POD type it's quite possible that `new int` and `new int[1]` do exactly the same thing under the covers, but if this is the case then `delete[]` on and `int*` and `delete` on an `int*` will also do exactly the same thing.)

ISO/IEC 14882:2011 5.3.5 [expr.delete] / 2:

> In the first alternative (*delete object*), the value of the operand of `delete` may be a null pointer value, a pointer to a non-array object created by a previous *new-expression*, or a pointer to a subobject (1.8) representing a base class of such an object (Clause 10). If not, the behavior is undefined.

As `int[1]` is an array object, if you try and delete it with `delete` and not `delete[]`, the behavior is undefined.

Comment: Can you please refer me back to the standards?

Comment: @Abhijit: It's not stated in the standard, so I can't give you a section number, but for the same reason it's not allowed.

Comment: In addition to the *delete-expression* restrictions, there are restrictions to the Standard Library deallocation function: "Otherwise, the behavior is undefined if the value supplied to `operator delete(void*)` in the standard library is not one of the values returned by a previous invocation of either `operator new(std::size_t)` or operator `new(std::size_t, const
std::nothrow_t&)` in the standard library [...]" (+ the same for the array (de)alloc) [basic.stc.dynamic.deallocation]/3

Answer (score 6):

The rule is quite simple:

1. always balance a `new` with a `delete`
2. always balance a `new[]` with a `delete[]`

otherwise you get *undefined behaviour*.

There are **no** exceptions; even `new[1]` must be balanced with a `delete[]`, and `new[0]` must be deleted as the compiler can still reserve storage.

Comment: IIRC, `new[0]` wasn't allowed.

Comment: If I recall correctly. I don't see anything from a quick standard sweep, though, so perhaps I remembered wrong or ran into a faulty compiler error, or perhaps I was thinking of a normal array.

Comment: I remember allocating new[0] by mistake a few years ago. But that compiler didn't even scope the for loop correctly! I'm upgrading my compiler today (to C++11): will re-check.

Comment: [You can allocate an array of size zero](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6180012/array-with-size-0)

Comment: It seems to work fine in any form for me. I really think it was stack-allocated arrays I was thinking of.

Answer (score 2):

> Should we delete the object using operator `delete[]` or `operator delete`?

`operator delete[]`. You have allocated an **array** of `int`s, so there's no other option for correctly deallocating it. Using `operator delete` would invoke undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2):

You must use `delete[]`.

C++11 5.3.5 Delete

> ::opt delete cast-expression
>
> ::opt delete [ ] cast-expression
>
> The first alternative is for non-array objects, and the second is for arrays.

An array holding one element is still an array.

Answer (score 1):

```
int *arr = new int[1];
```

Since you use `[]` for allocation, you need to use `[]` for `delete`as well.

> [Memory leaks](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new)
>
> The objects created by new expressions (objects with dynamic storage
>   duration) persist until the pointer returned by the new expression is
>   used in a **matching** delete-expression.

So you should use `delete[]` for releasing the memory or else you get undefined behaviour.

And <sub>(incase)</sub>, if the complier is smart enough to take `int * arr = new int[1]` as `int`, It must be smart enough to take `delete[] arr` on `arr` as `delete arr`. **However**, there is nothing for `delete` to differentiate between the `arr` from `int*arr = new int[1]` and `int*arr = new int`. The [`[]` in `delete`](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/allocate-array.html) is going to indicate it.

Answer (score 0):

**No its not safe, it may leads to some unwanted situations.**
For example,It is possible in a memory to have some data (`int/char/float`...) next to the location where your pointer points to. At that time if you used **`delete []`**  then it may try to delete that data too if it is an integer,for other data types it leads to unexpected errors. 

Example:

```
int *ptr = new int;
int a = 20;
char c = 'e';
*ptr = 10;
delete [] ptr;
```

There is a possibility the `c` and `a` variables may store next to the location where the pointer `ptr` points to, If `a` is stored next to it, then it deletes "`a`" also, if the other data types are present, leads to unexpected runtime results.

So it's advised to use `delete[]` only for the deletion of memory allocated using new datatype`[]`.Hope this is useful.

Comment: How would stack allocated variables end up next to heap allocated ones? How did you come up with that "possibility"?
Please refrain from writing just for the sake of writing.