# Is this code legal/portable? Accesing data outside of struct

Tags: c++, c++11

Based on a comment and [answer on my other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9574147/34537) I came out with this code. The comment was according to 5.3.4 New [expr.new] it is allowed to access outside of the struct as long as it is allocated. However I coudln't find the section that says that.

I came up with this code. I wanted to know if its portable and completely defined and legal. The output is kind of interesting. [in gcc](http://ideone.com/6JrVo) it is 10,10,12 while visual studios 2010 shows 12,10,12.

Is the code legal in C++11 or C++03? I believe the code will be align in any platform/cpu with a standard compiler.

-edit- In case your lazy flex_struct is the part that does questionable things.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <new>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

template <typename STRUCT, typename TYPE> class flex_struct {
    flex_struct(){}
public:
    //should be safe to access and check what length the array is
    static STRUCT* head(char*buff) {
        //is this next line wrong?
        //if((alignof(STRUCT)%reinterpret_cast<size_t>(buff))!=0) { throw std::exception(); }
        return reinterpret_cast<STRUCT*>(buff);
    }

    struct struct_with_array : public STRUCT { TYPE buf[1]; };

    TYPE* buff() {
        //if(length==0) { throw std::exception(); }
        auto p = reinterpret_cast<struct_with_array*>(this);
        return p->buf;
    }
};

typedef short testtype;

struct MyVariableLengthStruct : public flex_struct<MyVariableLengthStruct, testtype> {
    int a, b;
    char c;
};

struct MyVariableLengthStruct2 {
    int a, b;
    char c;
    testtype buf[1];
};
struct MyVariableLengthStruct3a {
    int a, b;
    char c;
};
struct MyVariableLengthStruct3 : MyVariableLengthStruct3a {
    testtype buf[1];
};
int main() {

    auto srcarray=new char[1024];
    //we don't actually need this line which is incorrect anyways (sizeof isnt 1024)
    //memset(srcarray, 0, sizeof(srcarray)); //whats a C++ way to do this w/o writing a loop or function?
    auto v = MyVariableLengthStruct::head(srcarray);
    auto buff = v->buff();
    auto dif1 = (int)buff-(int)v;
    printf("%X %X %d\n", v, buff, dif1);
    MyVariableLengthStruct2 v2;
    auto dif2 = (int)v2.buf-(int)&v2;
    printf("%X %X %d\n", &v2, v2.buf, dif2);
    MyVariableLengthStruct3 v3;
    auto dif3 = (int)v3.buf-(int)&v3;
    printf("%X %X %d\n", &v3, v3.buf, dif3);
}
```

Comment: You want to know if it's portable, while you already know that it isn't?

Comment: `sizeof(srcarray)` is not 1024, it's the same as `sizeof(char*)`.

Comment: Try to clarify your code and questions. Number the questions.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: What the heck!?! I could swear that would be 1024. I'm positive i done it years ago on gcc and visual studios (but not vs6). Funny enough thats the line i asked for a C++ version cause... that error is too easy to make.

Comment: `template <typename T> T* make_zeroed_array(size_t count) { T* ptr = new T[count]; std::fill(srcarray, srcarray + count, T()); return ptr; }`, if you must. Or just `std::vector<T> xs(1024)`.

Comment: @acidzombie24: The sizeof trick will only work with arrays of static size, but not with arrays allocated at runtime using `new[]`.

Comment: @acidzombie24: how can you have done it years ago? `auto` was only introduced in C++11. Which also answers the OP's question about C++03, I reckon ;)

Comment: `The comment was according to 5.3.4 New [expr.new] it is allowed to access outside of the struct as long as it is allocated. However I coudln't find the section that says that.` I can't find that comment.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: If you have to "number the questions", then there is more than one question in the question, which is a problem.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, yes, when you put two or more questions in the question, it is a problem.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: That's correct, as well as being what I just said.

Comment: @ComicSansMS: `sizeof` is not a trick.

Answer (score 4):

I see a lot of issues with this code.

```
    //is this next line wrong?
    //if((alignof(STRUCT)%reinterpret_cast<size_t>(buff))!=0) { throw std::exception(); }
    return reinterpret_cast<STRUCT*>(buff);
```

Memory returned from `new char[n]` is properly aligned for objects of the requested size or less. However, static and automatic `char` arrays are not. So, if you always pass something allocated with `new char[n]` here, there's no problem. If you pass a pointer to a static or automatic array, then alignment is a problem indeed.

```
struct struct_with_array : public STRUCT { TYPE buf[1]; };
```

Indexing out of array bounds is undefined behaviour. There is only one element of `buf` you can access. Note that this issue doesn't happen in the code in the original answer.

```
auto p = reinterpret_cast<struct_with_array*>(this);
```

I'm not entirely sure of the validity of this cast, but I suspect it breaks strict aliasing.

```
auto srcarray=new char[1024];
memset(srcarray, 0, sizeof(srcarray)); //whats a C++ way to do this w/o writing a loop or function?
```

The C++ way would be `std::vector<char>(1024);`, I guess. In any case `sizeof(srcarray)` is likely not 1024, but probably 4 or 8 (equal to `sizeof(char*)`).

```
auto v = MyVariableLengthStruct::head(srcarray);
```

There was never a `MyVariableLengthStruct` constructed in the memory pointed by `srcarray`, so this will only work for POD types.

Comment: 1) Indexing out of array bounds <-- That never happens assuming you check if the size of the array is >0 and don't call buff() blindly. 2) I vaguely remember aliasing rules. But IIRC as long as the buffer isn't read outside of the function before the function finish executing i should be safe. 3) Great, because I only want to do this with POD types. I need some kind of static_assert to make sure STRUCT is POD.

Comment: @acidzombie The size of the array is 1: `TYPE buf[1];`. The assert you want for PODness is `static_assert(std::is_pod<STRUCT>::value, "STRUCT should be POD");`.

Comment: Yep but i was actually trying to figure out why my struct failed. I'm testing MyVariableLengthStruct3. I'll figure it out and comment later

Comment: No, arrays don't make it non-POD. Arrays of standard layout types have standard layout. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7189821/46642). I'm a bit confused about the output code, though. `v2.buf - &v2`? Shouldn't that be negative? How can it be 10?

Comment: About POD http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9585720/why-isnt-this-a-pod-type-c11 well the address of v2.anymember is always >= v2. Even tho its on the stack structs are still X size and members are still in same layout as if it was on the heap. The first member is at offset 0, next member located at a > offset.