# Run-time sized array in a c++ struct

Tags: c++, arrays, struct, g++, flexible-array-member

In C (with gcc), I used to have some data structures that were an array with some extra information:

```
struct song {
    uint tempo;
    uint key;
    note play[0]; // or play[] depending on compiler flavour
};
```

Iirc, that's dubbed a "flexible array" (http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Zero-Length.html#Zero-Length) 
I could then allocate a song of N notes with `malloc(sizeof(song)+N*sizeof(note))` at run-time.
To what extent is that supported in g++, if I don't intend to use vectors this time, nor to introduce a useless `note*` pointer in `song` ?

Comment: "nor to introduce a useless note* pointer in song" - You amuse me. BTW `malloc` is C, `new` is C++

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9573748/variable-length-struct-nonstandard-in-c11?lq=1

Comment: @EdHeal: Incorrect. `malloc` is both C _and_ C++.

Comment: Yes - I agree - but `malloc` and `new` should not mix IMHO

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Even in C, this is undefined and non-portable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3711233/is-the-struct-hack-technically-undefined-behavior). GCC knowingly lets you get away with it, but other implementations may not. This is because you are accessing an array beyond its bounds.

[This "trick" is precisely as valid in C++ as it is in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9573748/variable-length-struct-nonstandard-in-c11?lq=1). That is, feel free to use it in GCC where the GCC documentation says it's supported, but it'll never be "well-defined, valid C++".

Comment: I vaguely remember that there was actually a pretty huge bug in some widely used OSS app due to reliance of out-of-bound pointer access. This may *seem* safe but it most decidedly is not, and the optimiser can pull some very funky stunts that render such code dangerous.

Answer (score -1):

there is no other way than using a fixed length or a note*
because the compiler must know how long your song-structs are, and every struct has the same lenght.

so you have to use a note* or a vector

Comment: I worry that this answer rejects or misses the premise of the flexible array hack.