# Preference between memcpy and dereference

Tags: c, memory, memcpy, dereference

When copying a known struct in memory, would you prefer using memcpy or dereference? why?
Specifically, in the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
    int foo;
    int bar;
} compound;

void copy_using_memcpy(compound *pto, compound *pfrom)
{
    memcpy(pto, pfrom, sizeof(compound));
}
void copy_using_deref(compound *pto, compound *pfrom)
{
    *pto = *pfrom;
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    compound a = { 1, 2 };
    compound b = { 0 };
    compound *pa = &a;
    compound *pb = &b;

    // method 1
    copy_using_memcpy(pb, pa);
    // method 2
    copy_using_deref(pb, pa);
    printf("%d %d\n", b.foo, b.bar);

    return 0;
}
```

Would you prefer method 1 or method 2? I looked at the assembly generated by gcc, and it seems that method 2 uses less instructions than method 1. Does it imply that method 2 is preferable in this case? Thank you.

Comment: I'd just use dereference+assignment instead of `memcpy()`. Simpler code. If there's any difference, it should be practically negligible with a good compiler.

Comment: Thank you Shao-Chuan Wang, your code triggers a bug in icc that I reported a while ago, but with a not-so-minimal example :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I can't think of any good reason to use `memcpy()` rather than an assignment when copying a struct (as long as you don't need to do a [deep copy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_copy#Deep_copy) or something involving the [struct hack](http://c-faq.com/struct/structhack.html) or a *flexible array member*, none of which apply in this case).

They have exactly the same semantics, and the assignment (a) likely gives the compiler more opportunities for optimization, and (b) has less risk of getting the size wrong.

Some *very* old C compilers probably didn't support struct assignment, but that's no longer a significant concern.

(There are additional reasons to prefer assignment in C++, but your question is about C.)

Incidentally, the parentheses in

```
(*pto) = (*pfrom);
```

are unnecessary; the unary `*` binds tightly enough that this:

```
*pto = *pfrom;
```

is both correct and sufficiently clear to most readers.

Comment: On a second thought, I found a case that we need to use memcpy instead of using pointer dereference. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/295027/array-of-zero-length  In this case, the size of struct does not reflect the exact size of "data" that it "contains".

Answer (score 3):

For the exact same reason you mentioned, I'd prefer method 2 (the dereferencing one). Memcpy does a byte-by-byte copy AND has the overhead of a function call, while the dereferencing does the copy only, and doesn't have the extra overhead.

Dereferencing and assigning is also more readable (especially when you omit the superfluous parentheses:

```
*dest = *src;
```

)

Comment: Memcpy doesn't necessarily have the overhead of a function call. :)

Comment: Memory copies are often inlined by the compiler, no call.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze well, think of TCC :)

Comment: Unless it's the ancient Turbo C(++), which is of approximately zero significance these days, I've never used it.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze No, it's the Tiny C Compiler, the only C compiler I know about that is widely used as a library, but does no optimizations.

Comment: That's OK for TCC, both TCCs. :)

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze very well said :)

Comment: We could say, it has the overhead of a function call, which might be zero overhead thanks to inlining. Meanwhile, the copy-by-dereferencing might *also* have the overhead of a function call, because the implementation is within its rights to implement struct copying by calling memcpy (or some other compiler-generated function that does the same thing). If the struct is above a certain size that could be sensible even if the `memcpy` isn't inlined, and it's certainly simple for the implementer.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to run this with Google's [benchmark](https://github.com/google/benchmark):

```c
#include <benchmark/benchmark.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
    int foo;
    int bar;
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    int d;
    int e;
    int f;
    int g;
} compound;

static void copy_using_memcpy(benchmark::State& state) {
    compound a = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    compound b = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    compound* pa = &a;
    compound* pb = &b;
    for (auto _ : state) memcpy(pa, pb, sizeof(compound));
}
static void copy_using_deref(benchmark::State& state) {
    compound a = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    compound b = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    compound* pa = &a;
    compound* pb = &b;
    for (auto _ : state) *pa = *pb;
}

BENCHMARK(copy_using_memcpy);
BENCHMARK(copy_using_deref);

BENCHMARK_MAIN();
```

The result is like:

```
> g++ benchmark.cc -lbenchmark -lpthread && ./a.out
2020-11-20T20:12:12+08:00
Running ./a.out
Run on (16 X 1796.56 MHz CPU s)
CPU Caches:
  L1 Data 32 KiB (x8)
  L1 Instruction 32 KiB (x8)
  L2 Unified 512 KiB (x8)
  L3 Unified 4096 KiB (x1)
Load Average: 0.29, 0.15, 0.10
------------------------------------------------------------
Benchmark                  Time             CPU   Iterations
------------------------------------------------------------
copy_using_memcpy       2.44 ns         2.44 ns    282774223
copy_using_deref        1.77 ns         1.77 ns    389126375
```

In the original example, with only two fields, the time is roughly the same.