# Array Creation Problems in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm a novice programmer trying to get a head start on some classes before the summer semester starts, and I've run into this problem while trying to create a Quick Union algorithm in C++.

I've been trying to figure out why my program creates two identical arrays, despite having two separate for loops designed to create two different arrays. Whenever my program runs to completion and prints id[] and sz[], it always outputs 1 as the element at every index in both arrays.

```
class quickUnionUF{
private:
    int id[];
    int sz[];
    int root(int);
public:
    quickUnionUF(int, int);
    bool connected(int, int);
    void unionPoint(int, int);
    void print();
};

quickUnionUF::quickUnionUF(int n, int b){
    id[n];
    sz[b];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        id[i] = i;
    }
    for(int j=0;j<b;j++){
        sz[j] = 1;
    }
}
```

For example, if I create quickUnionUF(5, 5);

id[] should now contains elements:

0, 1, 2, 3, 4

And sz[] contains elements:

1, 1, 1, 1, 1

However, the program creates an array sz[] AND array id[] with elements:

1, 1, 1, 1, 1

Any thoughts as to why this is happening?

Comment: That shouldn't compile in standard C++. You can't have flexible size arrays as data members.

Comment: `id` and `sz` are both empty arrays. So, any element you try to access causes undefined behaviour (basically, anything can happen, ranging from funny values to mutant dinosaurs breaking in from another dimension -- or it could work as expected, which is even worse, because it will break one day for no reason and you'll lose a week debugging it).

Comment: @juanchopanza: ILE C/C++ maybe?

Comment: Please go through the foundations of array - http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/arrays/

Comment: @staticx GCC also has an extension for this. But it doesn't look like it is being used correctly here anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code hints at a two very important mistakes:

1. C++ does not work like Java. `int id[]` is *not* an reference to an array of arbitrary size on the garbage collected heap. It is instead a member array of undefined size used to implement dynamic arrays (and similar features) [in C99](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295027/array-of-zero-length). You should never use this syntax unless you know exactly what you are doing, because it is almost guaranteed to be wrong otherwise.
2. `id[n]` does not allocate an array at all. Instead it just indexes `id` and discards the result.

#### Listen to your compiler!

First, your code *should not compile* due to the fact, that only the last member of a struct may be a flexible array type. In fact clang howls:

```
main.cpp:53:9: error: field has incomplete type 'int []'
    int id[];
```

MSVC howls:

```
1>main.cpp(54): error C2229: class 'quickUnionUF' has an illegal zero-sized array
```

And g++ only warns (well, g++ is strange in what it accepts sometimes):

```
main.cpp:53:12: warning: ISO C++ forbids zero-size array ‘id’ [-Werror=pedantic]
    int id[];
```

Note: g++ *is wrong in compiling this*, even if one allows flexible array members. This is defined in C99 6.7.2.1§16 and C11 6.7.2.1§18 both of which begin with (emphasis is mine):

> As a special case, the *last* element of a structure with more than one named member may
>   have an incomplete array type; this is called a flexible array member. [...]

#### What is happening?

Well, assuming you got your code to compile anyway, it basically means the following:

Create an object with the alignment of integers, but NO elements at all. Take a peek at the following test program:

```
quickUnionUF q;
::std::cout << sizeof(quickUnionUF) << "\n";
::std::cout << &q << "\n" << &q.id[0] << "\n" << &q.sz[0] << "\n";
```

The only compiler that managed to compile this at all (gcc 4.9.0) gave the following result:

```
0
0x7fff1bf6274c
0x7fff1bf6274c
0x7fff1bf6274c
```

So, this is a zero byte object (yes, this is illegal C++, since every C++ object has a size > 0) and the first element of each array is at the same position (OUTSIDE YOUR OBJECT!). Remember, you declared `id` and `sz` to have *zero* elements!

Therefore, you are writing to the same arbitrary position. You can consider this the extreme case of a buffer overflow: By writing 5 integers to a zero size buffer, you are overflowing from the first zero size buffer through the second zero size buffer into memory totally not under your control.

This also explains your observed result: The second loop simply overwrites what the first did (and it *still* does it by corrupting your stack).

#### How do I fix this?

Just use a [`vector`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/). You can tell it [how big you want it](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/resize/) and you can [ask it to tell you](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/at/) when you are indexing to some position that is not yours.

Comment: I see, a professor also answered the question for me earlier and he was perplexed as to why the code compiled in the first place as well! He told me to use a pointer int *id; if I really wanted to use arrays. Thanks for your help though!

Answer (score 4):

Standard C++ does not have sizeless array members.
Use `std::vector<int>` as dynamically sized arrays in C++.

```
#include <vector>
class quickUnionUF{
private:
    std::vector<int> id;
    std::vector<int> sz;
    int root(int);
public:
    quickUnionUF(int, int);
    bool connected(int, int);
    void unionPoint(int, int);
    void print();
};

quickUnionUF::quickUnionUF(int n, int b)
    : id(n)
    , sz(b)
{
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        id[i] = i;
    }
    for(int j=0;j<b;j++){
        sz[j] = 1;
    }
}
```