# C++ Zero Length Arrays in Header File

Tags: c++

From ISO/IEC 14882:2003 8.3.4/1:

> If the constant-expression (5.19) is present, it shall be an integral
>   constant expression and its       value shall be greater than zero.

Therefore the following should not compile:

```
#pragma once
class IAmAClass
{
public:
    IAmAClass();
    ~IAmAClass();

private:
    int somearray[0];    // Zero sized array
};
```

But it does. However, the following:

```
#pragma once
class IAmAClass
{
public:
    IAmAClass();
    ~IAmAClass();

private:
    int somearray[0];
    int var = 23;     // Added this expression
};
```

does not compile, with the following error (as what would be expected) (Visual C++)

```
error C2229: class 'IAmAClass' has an illegal zero-sized array
```

When the code is in a function, it, in accordance with the standard, will never compile.

So, why does the code behave in such a way in a header file, where the difference of the compilation passing or failing appears to be down to whether a statement proceeds the zero sized array declaration or not.

Comment: IIRC that's actually a C extension, allowing an arbitrary amount of data after the class data to be accessed. You'd need to manually allocate space for that data (via `malloc`).

Comment: @dyp, Flexible array members are valid as of C99.

Comment: @chris I know, was a shorthand for "C construct allowed as an extension in C++" ;)

Comment: By the way @Ben this is not a zero-sized array but an *array of unknown bound*, an incomplete type. A zero-sized array would be `int somearray[0];`

Comment: @dyp I see. I edited the question to take this into account as the actual zero sized array behaves in the same way.

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/296143/14065

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The keyword in "If the constant-expression (5.19) is present," is **if**. It's not, so the first version compiles.

However, such variant arrays are only permissible (and sane) when they are the *last* element in a `struct` or `class`, where it's expected that they'll use extra space allocated to the struct on a case-by-case basis.

If an unknown-length array were allowed *before* other elements, how would other code know *where* in memory to find those elements?

Comment: Data members of incomplete type are not allowed in C++.

Comment: g++ and others allow it, though. I'm not arguing the validity, just explaining what is *actually happening* in the OP's samples.

Comment: The first sentence is not an explanation why it compiles. You cannot use the Standard (which disallows this program) to explain why this is allowed.

Answer (score 3):

This is a Visual C++ language extension: [Declaring Unsized Arrays in Member Lists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d88dx3xf). From the linked MSDN page:

> Unsized arrays can be declared as the last data member in class member lists if the program is not compiled with the ANSI-compatibility option (`/Za`)

---

Edit: If the member has been declared as a *zero-sized array* (like `int somearray[0];`) instead of an array of unknown bounds (like `int somearray[];`), this is *still* a language extension, albeit [a different one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wkxxx2e%28v=vs.71%29.ASPX)

> A zero-sized array is legal only when the array is the last field in a struct or union and when the Microsoft extensions (/Ze) are enabled.

---

This extension is similar to C99's *flexible array members* C11/n1570 §6.7.2.1/18

> As a special case, the last element of a structure with more than one named member may have an incomplete array type; this is called a *flexible array member*.

and /20 contains an example:

> EXAMPLE 2    After the declaration:
>
> ```
> struct s { int n; double d[]; };
> ```
>
> the structure `struct s` has a flexible array member `d.` A typical
>   way to use this is:
>
> ```
> int m = /* some value */;
> struct s *p = malloc(sizeof (struct s) + sizeof (double [m]));
> ```
>
> and assuming that the call to `malloc` succeeds, the object pointed to
>   by `p` behaves, for most purposes, as if `p` had been declared as:
>
> ```
> struct { int n; double d[m]; } *p;
> ```
>
> [...]