# Purpose of char a[0] in converting integer to string using itoa()

Tags: c++

I have this code,

```
char a[0];
cout << "What is a? " << a << endl;
char *word = itoa(123,a,10);
string yr = string(word);
```

but i have trouble comprehending the array a[0]. I tried to change its value and see if there is any changes, but it seems to make no differences at all.

example, even if a change a[0] to a[1], or any other integer, the output still make no difference

```
char a[1];
cout << "What is a? " << a << endl;
char *word = itoa(123,a,10);
string yr = string(word);
```

What is its purpose here?

Comment: is it `char a[0]` (as in the code) or `char a[1]` (as in the title) ? What do you mean with "tried to change its value" ? Can you provide a [mcve] ?

Comment: oh sorry it's a[0], and by changing the value, i mean the integer in a[0] to a[1], and so on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since [`itoa` function is non-standard](https://stackoverflow.com/q/190229/335858), this is a discussion of a popular signature `itoa(int, char*, int)`.

Second parameter represents a buffer into which a null-terminated string representing the value is copied. It must provide enough space for the entire string: in your case, that is `"123"`, which takes four characters. Your code passes `a[]` as the buffer, but the size of `a[]` is insufficient to accommodate the entire `"123"` string. Hence, the call causes [undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4105123/335858).

You need to make `a` large enough to fit the destination string. Passing a buffer of size 12 is sufficient to accommodate the longest decimal number that can be produced by `itoa` on a 32-bit system (i.e. `-2147483648`). Replace `char a[0]` with `char a[12]` in the declaration.

Answer (score 1):

> What is its purpose here?

A zero-length array is an array with no elements in it.

You can't [legally] print or modify its contents, because it doesn't have any.

[There are arcane reasons to want to use one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/295027/560648), but speaking generally it has no purpose for you. It's not even allowed by the standard (although compilers tend to support it for those arcane reasons).

> even if a change a[0] to a[1], or any other integer, the output still make no difference

Well, if you have an array with *n* elements in it, and you write more than *n* elements' worth of data to it, that's a "buffer overrun" and has undefined behaviour. It could appear to work as you overwrite somebody else's memory, or your program could crash, or your dog could suddenly turn into a zombie and eat you alive. Best avoided tbh.

Comment: I would mention that zero length array variables are ill-formed in C++ (although probably supported as language extension).

Comment: @user2079303: Hum, didn't even know that, but you're right.